# Asynchronously wait for Task<T> without async/await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I want my `Task` to complete before I perform other actions. If I use

```
Task.WaitAll(task);
```

it certainly blocks my UI thread. What is the best way to wait asynchronously for a `Task` to complete, without using `async / await` (I'm using .NET v4.0)?

Comment: The concept of waiting asynchronously is hurting my brain...

Comment: Why not just run it synchronously?

Comment: You can only compose continuations (`ContinueWith`). That being said, you *can* use async & await and target .NET 4. You have to use VS2012 though, with [Async Targeting Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async).

Comment: what's the point of making asynchronous calls if it's to wait for them to complete. It's same thing as taking a 1 lane road split it to 8 lane and come back 1 lane.

Comment: Hmm, if you really mean "how do I call a method when a certain task has completed", then @user2834880 has the right answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `async / await` also in .NET 4.0 when you add the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async NuGet package` to your project. Besides this, you have not much choice - either you use asynchronous calls or your block your thread with the method you mentioned already.

However, you're not bound to `await` when using asynchronous method. You can also use a callback:

```
task.ContinueWith(r => {
    /* code */
});
```

Comment: If `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` isn't an option, then `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll` is a good replacement for `Task.WaitAll`.